# Seek bar in mp3 file not working

Tags: html, mp3, html5-audio

I have been trying to play the mp3 file in browser using default html5 player.

http://ujyaaloonline.com/audios/programAudios/1a8fdf5d0433ed581bbcee74836b3305.mp3

Audio is playing but the seek bar is not working here. What might be the problem. Please help.

Comment: You can't seek a live stream (its an mp3 file but it seems to be somehow generated in real-time). If you want seeking you'll have to store bytes as you receive them & make your own player seek/play within stored bytes. I don't know if that's even possible with html-5 alone. Google for **html5 sockets**, **getting bytes into buffer** and **playing from bytes buffer**

Answer (score 2):

You need to [support byte range requests](http://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/206-partial-content-and-range-requests/) on the machine from which you're serving the audio. See SoundManager2's [Technical Notes on the subject](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/technotes/#byte-serving).

> Byte Serving is automatically negotiated between client and server, and offers a number of advantages over traditional downloads. Most notably, Byte Serving is closer to a "streaming" technology and enables clients to seek, buffer and resume playback at arbitrary positions within a file once the duration is known.

Example Request:

```
GET 1a8fdf5d0433ed581bbcee74836b3305.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=5210604-5275910
```

Expected Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-length: 65307
Content-Range: bytes 5210604-5275910/5275911
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
```

1. You don't appear to be sending the [`206 Partial Content`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.7) status.
2. You're not sending a proper `Content-Range` response header.
3. Finally if the client makes a range request that is out of bounds—that is, none of the range values overlap the extent of the resource—the server should respond with a [`416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.17) status.