# Unable to Skip Audio in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I have an audio tag and I'm unable to skip forwards or backwards.  The audio file itself plays fine.

HTML:

```
<audio controls="" controlslist="nodownload"><source src="http://myserver:1340/api/v1/media/mediaAsset/s3/groupId/25/variantId/6?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtleSI6ImJ3QXV0aFBsYXRmb3JtIiwiYXVkIjoiYndBdXRoUGxhdGZvcm0iLCJzdHJhdGVneSI6ImNsb3VkVXNlciIsImlkIjo3NiwiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiVGVzdCIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiRWRpdG9yIiwiZW1haWwiOiJ0ZXN0LmVkaXRvckBidXNpbmVzc3dpcmUuY29tIiwicG9ydHJhaXQiOiIiLCJjb25uZWN0QWNjb3VudCI6MTAxMDM3NiwidGltZXpvbmUiOi01LCJjaXR5IjoiTmV3IFlvcmsiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODU5NTcwODUsImV4cCI6MTU4NTk1NzEwNX0.N6EXY4ELNrqMHHSIBz7NU2CVH0BLYaMwMMSqqhyToPij_OCkAqzOhaIxHzs6NGcRYojtEngOECu5WcM2GJHCD4BmAHZJTMlFWdSVDNj2wv-oUz8DjmTDzBYPAXrgr0_RPVBPlTJNOFhAt1QWwcvPr__OG-WGOgnieiCjqS2VgVCOrEBKAKlBqEamaOcCOw54hf9axBGcXE-I-_ZvvFNwt08fDodiR--gjcb46z64c5KGl5CbPyTOc0x6qjXTy-iFMdZLhqmzL6hR-XrHaPt8RyNQBzzb3ReBiY3xLL4sDZdkvc4-fcg2Go2-zYPBBOXMALxc3xUMPSb1rBOx-Sr80Q" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

HTTP response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-disposition: inline; filename=Audio.mp3
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 23:31:43 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=3600
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
X-Powered-By: Express
X-RequestID: undefined
X-XSS-Protection: 1
```

Comment: The response is supposed to contain a `Content-Length` and `Content-Range` headers, otherwise, the browser does not know what range to request to the server. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744718/seek-bar-in-mp3-file-not-working). Can you show us how you serve your mp3 file, on your Express server?

Comment: @blex, in that question it mentioned `Content-Range` as well.  Is that required?

Comment: Yes, I edited my comment. I did that once, a couple of years ago, so I did not remember immediatly. It's in this form `{start_of_range}-{end_of_range}/{total_length}`. The total length allows the browser to know up to where it can go, and the range is what it loads for this specific request. And `Content-Length` is the length of the range for this specific request